# Check if string contains \n Java

Tags: java, string

How do I check if string contains \n or new line character ?

```
word.contains("\\n")
word.contains("\n")
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If the string was constructed in the same program, I would recommend using this:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
boolean hasNewline = word.contains(newline);
```

But if you are specced to use \n, this driver illustrates what to do:

```
class NewLineTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hasNewline = "this has a newline\n.";
        String noNewline = "this doesn't";

        System.out.println(hasNewline.contains("\n"));
        System.out.println(hasNewline.contains("\\n"));
        System.out.println(noNewline.contains("\n"));
        System.out.println(noNewline.contains("\\n"));

    }

}
```

Resulted in

```
true
false
false
false
```

In reponse to your comment:

```
class NewLineTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "test\n.";
        System.out.println(word.length());
        System.out.println(word);
        word = word.replace("\n","\n ");
        System.out.println(word.length());
        System.out.println(word);

    }

}
```

Results in

```
6
test
.
7
test
 .
```

Comment: Works but s = s.replace("\n", " \n "); does not replace new line with new line and spaces.

Comment: Yes it does. Updating my answer. It clearly shows a space after the newline.

Answer (score 11):

For portability, you really should do something like this:

```
public static final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator")
.
.
.
word.contains(NEW_LINE);
```

unless you're absolutely certain that `"\n"` is what you want.

Answer (score 8):

The second one:

```
word.contains("\n");
```

Comment: could you clarify why it doesn't work.  What is your input, what is the result and what is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry about that I had not restarted my tomcat after rebuilding JAr so it didnt make effect.It works now although Replace s = s.replace("\n", " \n "); is not working .

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather trust JDK over System property.
Following is a working snippet.

```
    private boolean checkIfStringContainsNewLineCharacters(String str){
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(str)){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
            scanner.nextLine();
            boolean hasNextLine =  scanner.hasNextLine();
            scanner.close();
            return hasNextLine;
        }
        return false;
    }
```