# How come my split("\n") isn't working

Tags: java, netbeans

I've tried "\n\n" and "\r" and everything else, including replaceAll("\r\n", "n") and I still do not understand why it doesn't work. I've also tried "\w", "\n", "\n+" - I've basically tried everything under "My split("\n") doesn't work" on Google search.

I'm trying to split a word with a lot of "\n". I basically have two different classes. One generates this word, and via the other class constructor object transfers it into the split("\n") method. But whatever I do, the array still stays empty.

I've also tried word.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")) even though I didn't have a clue as to what it meant, but it also came up under one of the solutions to this problem.

Here's my Code:

```
//in Class A

public String getWord()
{
    word = word +"\n" +  horizontal;
    return word;
}

//in Class B

classA a = new classA();
String grid = a.getWord();
String [] lines = grid.split("\n");
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, typo mistake, I'll just ask again later. I did actually put `grid.split("\n")` in my code. What now? The array really is empty. I did `System.out.println(array.length)` and it was 0. Also, I typed `System.out.println("array is " + array)` and it only gave me "array is" as output. I know I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere, and I know I can't expect people to answer my question if I don't know what info to provide.

I also wanted to add some stuff in the comments section here for the comfort of those sitting in front of their laptops...

word and horizontal is a string. It's actually a crossword puzzle together. 
See? Look!

```
LONDONPYVRAOMNDDEFSG
GCPZVBATHYXAZXEZIMOZ
NKDGBERLINCHPLTMHMSM
ZMUKPGCHRKDTYGIMRLHO
TVRWBXPRETORIAJBVKWT
OGIVSDFULULHQHAHEJNV
PNWEJHBAKBJZNBPARIS
PHKCZCYGTXEEXDUCPMXF
QIMQMABRASILIALJOFJQ
GXNXKTAHIQMMIFPSYDLI
CAIROYKZYSWEFPUZPKRG
BTNAUNIDQAYVYAPGWWIN
QXZMQSZBTCBEIJINGBSD
QWQRYTBPTKRBCJUOMJTV
SODHAMSTERDAMEMSLVAM
YQHEVNXQQJXCDZKEYQVT
NAIROBISVDNTCFJNYDEG
AKXVOIGYTZTJHGIAFIKZ
BAGHDADSADJTWOOMVRYT
YCPOBXQQMQKBTDMYPYWT
```

It's city names. At the end of this, I'm supposed to show the solution to the puzzle by changing cases. I know how to do this, but the problem is that I can't seperate them into lines anymore. I don't know why. That's my only problem here. It seems to work for everyone, except for me.

Answers with clues will be appreciated? To delve into a dark and deep mystery...

Comment: What is the initial value you're giving `word`?

Comment: *"But whatever I do, the array still stays empty."* I very much doubt that. The array may have a *single* entry in it, but it won't be empty.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't make any sense. For one thing, you're calling `split` on `a` (an instance of `classA`), not on `grid` (the variable referencing the string returned by `a.getWord`).

Comment: You call `a.split()` but `a` is not a string. What is the split implementation in `a`?

Comment: If yours was a typo and you are calling `split` on `grid` instead of `a`, then your example should work: [IDEone](http://ideone.com/97eTKD)

Comment: Does the \n still carry the same value if it is transferred to another class? Because the split ("\n" really doesn't seem to work the way it should....

Comment: "I've also tried word.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")) even though I didn't have a CLUE as to WHAT it meant, but it also came up under one of the solutions to this problem." Please don't do that. Adding code that you don't understand to a problem you can't solve will only give you a second problem to solve.

Comment: Also, I've edited the post for you. Try to keep comments as comments and not put too much commentary in the question itself (if it's not directly related to the problem, it'll only make it harder for us to see exactly what you're looking for). Thanks for editing instead of creating a new question though; that's *exactly* the right way to go about it.

Comment: I know... But that's my way of learning ... Or panicking... or whatever :) Thanks for your tip, Dennis ^^ I still have a long way to go 0_~ Including interacting with my peers on StackOve ^^

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
grid.split("\n");
```

not

```
instance.split("\n")
```

Comment: It was actually a typo on my part >< I did actually do grid.split("\n") in my code. I didn't copy paste it...darn! My bad :)

Comment: But since you get points if I mark it correct, and you took the time to read my post, I'll just do it ^^ I'm going to delete my question anyway- once it lets me ^^

Comment: I'll probably come up later and ask my question again, since I still have the prob though. Once I know which info to provide you guys with, and I'm SURE I DIDN'T MAKE ANY MISTAKES, I'll post again -__- You guys are quite fast answering, you know that? :D

Comment: I know I marked it correct, but I still wish I knew WHY my code won't work... :'( Has anyone else actually TRIED this before?

Comment: @breakstorm please read the javadocs of split you was calling it on object

Comment: I did fix the typo didn't I ? I did do it on the String, I just didn't type it on the website here correctly >< And I meditated on the javadocs- just so you know. To brace myself for the invisible critics on the internet...

Comment: I'm just unticking for now, so that people will still be encouraged to answer :D I need more clues as to what went wrong.At the end of the day, I'll still tick it right back ^^

Answer (score 0):

Call `grid.split("\n");`

You can't split a class.

Better `a.getWord().split("\n");`

Answer (score 0):

In your code there isn't no method named split , also your didn"t call your method getword inside System.out.println()  ....
First Class :

```
public class A {
public String returnedWord ="";

   public String getWord(String word , String horizontal)
      {
           returnedWord = word +"\n" +  horizontal;
           return returnedWord ;
      }


}
```

the Second Class :

```
public class B {

public String word = "Hello";
public String horizontal = "World";
public static void main (String [] args ) {


    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.getword(word,horizontal));

}

}
```

you will get the output below :

```
Hello 
World
```

Comment: But the thing is that it works like that in any case if you do "\n"...What I wanted to do was to seperate it into lines as strings or whatever...

Comment: Like if my "grid" is "something\nsomething\nsomething" and I do split("\n") then it would store it as an array [something, something, something]  :) You get me?

Comment: so you want to manipulate any object or component , but your first question is about String not object or component !!

Comment: No, literally! I didn't come here to fight :/ My question was why isn't my split ("\n") not working. That was all I wanted to know. I don't mean to "manipulate any object or component", whatever that means. Because I'm still dealing with a string, if anything- I'm just creating an array from the string....Well, let's stop fighting ^^ This isn't helping me... much

Comment: that nice :) , i not in fight too :) , try to see these solution in this topic : [Check if string contains \n Java
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518451/check-if-string-contains-n-java) good luck